# Document field must regex match one item in array

Tags: database, couchdb, cloudant

I have a cloudantDB instance which uses CouchDB query syntax. At a high level, inside my database I have documents which contain id values as such

```
{
  "id": "123-01"
},
{
  "id": "123-02"
},
{
  "id": "456-01"
},
{
  "id": "789-01"
}
```

What I am attempting to achieve is to query for all of the documents who's `id` field starts with `123` and `456`, but not `789`. Currently, I have achieved this by creating a large selector which uses the `$or` operator to match any `$regex` condition like:

```
{
  selector: {
    "$or": [{
      "id": {
        "$regex": "123"
      }
    },
      "id": {
        "$regex": "456"
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

Something tells me that this is not a proper way to achieve this result. Might anyone know of a more efficient way to query the database for documents like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to get documents with ID starting of a specific prefix, consider using [_all_docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#get--db-_all_docs) with a `startkey`. That should be a more elegant and more performant solution (instead of using regexes).